# React inlined SVG paths are not responding to css animations

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, css-animations

I uploaded my code and svgs to this [github repo](https://github.com/stackoverflowsam93/svg-css-animations).

I have some svgs of some circles, blobs and triangles. I am trying to make the circles shake, like how the guy shakes in [this code pen when you hover on him](https://codepen.io/sdras/pen/aOgMON), I am trying to make the blobs move like [waves like in this code pen](https://codepen.io/liquidcharcoal/pen/rEeYrw), and I'm trying to make the triangles spin around. The blobs and triangles are not responding at all, even though I can see that they have the styling applied when I inspect the html. The circles have some effect, but not the one I want.

[image]
[image]

---

Here is the code for each

**circles.scss**

```css
    .circles > circle {
        animation: shake 2.2s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
    }
    
    @keyframes shake {
      10%, 90% {
        transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
      }
      
      20%, 80% {
        transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
      }
    
      30%, 50%, 70% {
        transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
      }
    
      40%, 60% {
        transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
      }
    }
```

**triangles.scss**

```css
    .triangles > g > path {
        animation: triangle-animation 2.2s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
    }
    
    @keyframes triangle-animation {
      10%, 90% {
        tranform: rotate(5deg);
      }
      
      20%, 80% {
        tranform: rotate(90deg);
      }
    
      30%, 50%, 70% {
        tranform: rotate(180deg);
      }
    
      40%, 60% {
        tranform: rotate(30deg);
      }
      100% { 
          tranform: rotate(0deg);
      }
    }
```

**waves.scss**

```css
    .waves > path {
      animation: wave-animation 4s infinite alternate;
    //   animation-duration: 4s;
    //   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    //   animation-direction: alternate;
    }
    
    @keyframes wave-animation {
      0%   {
        margin-left:0px;
        margin-top:0px;
        }  
      50%  {
        margin-left:-2000px;
        margin-top:200px;
        }  
      100% {
        margin-left:0px; 
        margin-top:0px;
        }
    }
```

And this is my main App.js file

```js
    import React from 'react';
    
    import Blobs from 'svg/Blobs.svg'
    import Circles from 'svg/Circles.svg';
    import Triangles from 'svg/Triangles.svg';
    
    export default () => (
        <div>
            <Circles className="circles" />
            <Blobs className=" w-100 h-100 waves" />
            <Triangles className='w-100 triangles' />                
        </div>
    );
```

The styles are imported in `index.js`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create components with the svg code inside then add your css classes ...
I advise you to start from scratch and create your own svg, it's easier than using already created svg.

(check the demo at the bottom of the page with the triangles, circles and waves)

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

import Triangles from './svg/Triangles';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Triangles />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Triangles.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Triangles() {
  return (
    <div className="triangles">
      <svg className="triangle one">
        <path d="M150 0 L30 200 L270 200 Z" />
      </svg>
      <svg className="triangle two">
        <path d="M120 0 L30 180 L200 200 Z" />
      </svg>
      <svg className="triangle three">
        <path d="M10 0 L40 280 L190 170 Z" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**style.css**

```
/* Triangles */
.triangles {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}
.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  fill: rgb(23, 233, 224);
  fill-opacity: 0.4;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.triangle.one {
  height: 210px;
  width: 300px;
  animation-duration: 5000ms;
}
.triangle.two {
  height: 150px;
  width: 400px;
  animation-duration: 9000ms;
}
.triangle.three {
  height: 120px;
  width: 300px;
  animation-duration: 3000ms;
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

**Demo :** [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ci9xqw?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: Thanks, I'm wondering if you might know what's wrong with this also, I'm trying to make one circle shake at random every few seconds, I set a timer up to do this and set equalities so that only one circle should get assigned to shake at a time, but it looks like one circle shakes on initial load, and then one only shakes if I make an edit to the code or refresh. I took the [code in your demo, and changed it a bit to try to have this functionality](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8qmwdd?file=src%2Fsvg%2FCircles.js)